# Multiple virtual host in Centos 7 is not working together

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host, vhost

My server information is

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13
```

I am trying to configure virtual host for 2 different sites: biz.example.com and pin.example.com which are hosted on the same server. There are 2 different folders located under 'var/www/html/' named 'biz' and 'pin' with their respected project files for the above mentioned 2 websites. I am trying to configure it on the below way.

Within /etc/hosts below configuration

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx biz.example.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx pin.example.com
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is replaced by the server IP address.

Within  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Now, under /etc/httpd/sites-available there are biz.conf and pin.conf file. I also have the folder sites-enabled under /etc/httpd which has 2 files that points to the biz.conf and pin.conf of sites-available folder using the below command

```
ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/biz.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/biz.conf

ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/pin.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/pin.conf
```

biz.conf has the followings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://biz.example.com/
ServerAlias http://biz.example.com/
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/biz"
<directory "/var/www/html/biz">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the configuration within pin.conf file is mentioned as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://pin.example.com/
ServerAlias http://pin.example.com/
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pin"
<directory "/var/www/html/pin">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On this setup, if i try to access http://biz.example.com/ , the correct website (biz website) is loading. But if i try to access http://pin.example.com/ , then also biz website is loading instead of pin website. Multiple configuration is not working together.

I also tried to merge the virtual configuration of biz.conf and pin.conf within a single file, biz.conf, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Are there error messages from Apache (this is Apache, right?) in its own log files or syslog messages?

Comment: I know is late post - but don't need http just domain `example.com` and you don't need trailing slash or quotes.. and allow from 127.0.0,1 - would that mean that only localhost can access localhost? surely access from all and enable cphulk?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1) Have to remove the trailing slash from ServerName and ServerAlias

2) Here, we can remove the ServerAlias as well as ServerName and ServerAlias both are same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes from your path

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pin
<directory /var/www/html/pin>
```

Answer (score 0):

> On this setup, if i try to access http://biz.example.com/ , the correct website (biz website) is loading. But if i try to access http://pin.example.com/ , then also biz website is loading instead of pin website.

That's because both `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives don't match (wrong syntax) and in this case the first defined `VirtualHost` gets all requests.

The behaviour is described in the documentation with a very similar config:

[Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address (httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#purename)

> ```
> # Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
> Listen 80
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
>     ServerName www.example.com
>
>     # Other directives here
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
>     ServerName www.example.org
>
>     # Other directives here
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> The asterisks match all addresses, so the main server serves no requests. Due to the fact that the virtual host with `ServerName www.example.com` is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the *default* or *primary* server. That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified `ServerName` directives, it will be served by this first `<VirtualHost>`.

---

**Solution:**

1. The `ServerName` must be without `http://` prefix and without trailing slash, i.e.

   ```
   ServerName biz.example.com
   ```

   and

   ```
   ServerName pin.example.com
   ```
2. `ServerAlias` can be removed since it has the same value as `ServerName`
3. `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` should start with a capital letter
4. The old Apache 2.2 access control syntax should be changed to the new Apache 2.4 `Require` syntax.

   ```
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   ```

   should be replaced by

   ```
   Require local
   ```

   See

   - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html
   - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives

---